# Google Messenger: Incorrect profile letter

Tags: profiles, google-messages

I recently moved from Hangouts to Messenger as my default SMS app.

The profile letter icon against the messages I send is showing to be incorrect (letter 'S' instead of 'R' which shows up on other Google apps that I use). I have since changed my Google profile picture but even that does not show up, 'S' persists.

I am not sure if this is a bug or if my account has been compromised.

Any help to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

It happens when you save your own phone number with someone's else name by mistake. If it's the case, you just need to double tap on the wrong "letter" (which is "S" in your case) that is showing next to your text messages and you'll be able to change the name associated with the texts.

Comment: I double checked my contacts (i use a Nexus 5) and this is not the case.

Comment: Did you double tap on the wrong letter and change the contact name associated with it?

Comment: Nope! I have not stored my own number in my contacts list. Neither have I any other contact who shares my name. Also no double tap is enabled on profile letter in the messenger app.

Comment: I'm sorry then this must be something else. I ran into the similar issue on my Galaxy S4 so I thought of sharing this solution with you.

Comment: Do you have a contact for yourself and a contact called "Me" in your Contacts app?